# valgrind: mmap(0x600000, 8192) failed in UME with error 12 (Cannot allocate memory)

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

I was following [this exercise](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex4.html). This page has instructions to install Valgrind 3.6.1 but this version of Valgrind is not supported by my current Linux kernel version. So, I installed Valgrind 3.11.0 and followed the instructions there after and on running this command:

```
  $ valgrind ./ex4
```

got this error:

```
valgrind: mmap(0x600000, 8192) failed in UME with error 12 (Cannot allocate memory).
```

How to do I fix it?

**I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with kernel version 4.4.0**

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want to install it?  Do you want to test it for segmentation fault on one of your programs?

Comment: It looks like you were planning to give a reference to the code you're trying to run.  Can you add the URL?  Do you have a sensibly configured machine or VM with enough memory?  Have you been able to run Valgrind on any other programs yet?  Are you running on 32-bit or 64-bit builds?  Although the article/link you're using must be fairly old to suggest Valgrind 3.6.1, you were correct to upgrade to 3.11.0 and things should work much the same with the new version as they once would have done with the older version.

Comment: You need this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1301093

Comment: I'm using native linux machine. I'm not able to run Valgrind on any program. My linux machine is 64-bit. I have added a url for the instructions and code which i'm following

Comment: @abhishek_naik: That link is very precisely on target — maybe you should convert it into an answer.  (Let me know if you do — a response comment to this, for example.)  Shyam: you almost certainly need to get an updated version of Valgrind (possibly from source) to be OK.  It's not your fault: you did nothing wrong per se, but the Linux kernel changed under `valgrind`, and it is more easily affected by kernel changes than many programs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I have posted the answer.  Please feel free to edit, if you think that the answer can be made better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error which you have encountered is actually a kernel bug, which was fixed in the subsequent versions.  More details here: 
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1301093

To overcome the error, I would suggest you to update the kernel.
**Note**: I am myself using running Ubuntu 14.04 on kernel version 3.16.0-67 and it runs without any hassles.

**Edit**:  As pointed out by the OP in comments, the bug has been fixed in kernel version 4.5.2.

Comment: @ShyamSaini accept the answer if you think it helps

Comment: @abhishek_naik I already have my machine with latest linux kernel which is version 4.4.0. As you said it is working with kernel version 3.16.0-67 but what about the latest one that my machine is running on?

Comment: @ShyamSaini, I would suggest you to boot from another kernel version.  If you are unsure how boot from an another version, please refer the beginning of the accepted answer of http://askubuntu.com/questions/738790/stopping-system-v-runlevel-compatibility-ubuntu-14-04-lts.

Comment: @abhishek_naik I already checked for another kernel version, its working fine in my machine. But i want it to work on kernel version 4.4.0.

Comment: It will become available once the kernel is updated and the bug, fixed; if not already available.

Comment: @abhishek_naik The bug has been fixed in kernel version 4.5.2. So , i edited your answer.