# Error with running valgrind: mmap(0x600000, 8192) failed in UME with error 12 (Cannot allocate memory)

Tags: c++, valgrind, macports

I am looking for an answer to my question, but unfortunately i didn't find something helpful.

Im using mac with sierra.

i was installed Valgrind and  macports and i did all the install commands.

Now when I'm trying to run a program with valgrind command i get this error every time :

> valgrind: mmap-FIXED(0x0, 253952) failed in UME (load_segment1) with
>   error 12 (Cannot allocate memory).

What am I missing?

edit: i found this answer to the same problem :
[valgrind: mmap(0x600000, 8192) failed in UME with error 12 (Cannot allocate memory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375371/valgrind-mmap0x600000-8192-failed-in-ume-with-error-12-cannot-allocate-memo)

buy they talk about the valgrind version that is already updated in my mac.
i didnt understand if shuold i update the kernel or not,and if yes how to do it .